# Why isn't it printing the complete decimal?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int test,r,i=0;
    float f;
    cin>>test;
    i++;
    while ( test!=0 )
    {
        cin>>r;
        f = 4*r*r + 0.25;
        cout<<"Case "<<i<<":"<<" "<<f<<"\n";
        i++;
        test--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made this simple program which calculates the value of the expression `4*r*r+0.25`. Here `r` will always be an integer between 1 <= r <= 1000000. I have to print the value of the above expression upto two decimal places. However, when I input the values of `r` anything >=50, it shows the result only as `output.2`, i.e. for example, on inputting the value as `50`, it shows the result as `10000.2`. Why is this happening?
I tried using double as well instead of float but it didnt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the precision, e.g.:

```
f = 4*r*r + 0.25;    
cout<<"Case "<<i<<":"<<" "<< setprecision(2) << fixed << f<<"\n";
```

Output:

`10000.25`

Make sure to include `iomanip`.

Comment: But why does it work perfectly with values less than 50?

Comment: Also, on executing the program, it now shows the output as `1e+04` with `r` as `50` and `1.4e+04` with value of `r` as 60.

Comment: I want the output in the form as `10000.25`, like this.

Comment: @Qin The default precision for streams is 6.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am running it on Linux and it shows 1e+04.

Comment: I can attach a screenshot if anyone wants it.

Comment: @Qin Note the `fixed`. Without it you'd need `setprecision(7)` for `10000.25`.

Comment: Exactly. The keyword fixed was important. Why is it used?

Comment: @Qin: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/ "floating-point values are written using fixed-point notation: the value is represented with exactly as many digits in the decimal part as specified by the precision field (precision) and with no exponent part."

Answer (score 5):

By default, floating point values are printed with up to six significant figures. You can use the `setprecision` manipulator to specify more precision:

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::setprecision(10);  // specify up to 10 significant figures
```

There are at least two more problems you'll encounter for larger values:

- the calculation `4*r*r` uses integer arithmetic, and will overflow if the integer type isn't large enough. You might want to use `int64_t`, or a floating-point type, to support input values up to 1000000.
- `float` can only represent up to about seven decimal digits accurately, and so you'll still lose precision for values of `r` more than a few thousand. `double` should be enough for input values up to 1000000.

Comment: @Qin: Typically 15. (The standard library can tell you: `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`).

Comment: Then when I used plain double instead of float in the declaration (without setting the precision points), why didn't it work? It still showed 10000.2 as the output with input as 50.

Comment: @Qin: I answered that in the first sentence. So did two other answers. You need to use `setprecision` if you want to print values with more precision than the default.

Comment: No, that is what I am asking you. You said that by default, double has precision upto 15 digits. Then for input as 50 whose output will have 7 digits, why will I need setprecision?

Comment: @Qin Internally, `double` has a bit more than 15 decimal digits precision (53 binary digits, to be exact).  That has nothing to do with the precision used by the conversion routines, which defaults to 6, regardless of the internal precision.

Comment: @Qin: Because, by default, floating point values are printed with up to six significant figures, whether or not the floating point type can represent more figures accurately. That's just how the input/output library is specified.

Comment: Oh! My bad. Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I thought that if I use double, it can print accurately uptill 15 decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at some simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main (void) {
    std::cout << 10000.25 << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    std::cout << 10000.25 << "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
10000.2
10000.25
```

If you'd like to see this in action, I've included an example of this on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/YXDGaU).