# how to print two digits after decimal point in cpp

Tags: c++

How to print two digits after decimal point in cpp:

```
#include<iostream>  

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int n,bt[20],wt[20],tat[20],avwt=0,avtat=0,i,j; 
    cout<<"Enter total number of processes(maximum 20):"; 
    cin>>n; 
    cout<<"\nEnter Process Burst Time\n"; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        cout<<"P["<<i+1<<"]:"; 
        cin>>bt[i]; 
    } 
    wt[0]=0;    //waiting time for first process is 0 
    //calculating waiting time 
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        wt[i]=0; 
         for(j=0;j<i;j++) 
             wt[i]+=bt[j];
    } 
    cout<<"\nProcess\t\tBurst Time\tWaiting Time\tTurnaround Time"; 
    //calculating turnaround time 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
         tat[i]=bt[i]+wt[i]; 
         avwt+=wt[i]; 
         avtat+=tat[i]; 
         cout<<"\nP["<<i+1<<"]"<<"\t\t"<<bt[i]<<"\t\t"<<wt[i]<<"\t\t"<<tat[i]; 
    } 
    avwt/=i; 
    avtat/=i; 
    cout<<"\n\nAverage Waiting Time:"<<avwt; 
    cout<<"\nAverage Turnaround Time:"<<avtat; 
    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Are you planning to ask your question and post your code properly?

Comment: Most of the code is not relevant to the question itself....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't it printing the complete decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729574/why-isnt-it-printing-the-complete-decimal)

Comment: why didn't he just say print to the hundredths

Comment: `std::fixed` + `std::setpricision` should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [printing the correct number of decimal points with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed ;
std::cout << avwt;
```

Comment: `setprecision` works in terms of significant digits, not digits after the decimal point....

Comment: @IrrationalPerson - Check :)

Comment: You'll also need `std::fixed`, otherwise (as @TonyD says) this will set the number of significant figures, not decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

you can use printf

```
printf("%.2f", avwt);
```

note that you can also specify a number of digits to be printed before the `.`

Comment: oups typo... thanks!